# Page loads with Thanks Message but Can't receive email from my PHP/ HTML contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

Down here is my php code - very simple - but still i couldnt receive any email

```
<?php

    $from="email";
    $email="machiavelli1527@hotmail.com";
    $subject=$_POST['Subject'];
    $message=$_POST['Surname'];
    $message=$_POST['Gender'];
    $message=$_POST['telephone'];
    $message=$_POST['EnterEmail'];
    $message=$_POST['Message'];
    $message=$_POST['Receive'];
    $message=$_POST['Receive1'];

    mail ($email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);

    echo("Thank you $name for your interest in LTD.  We will be in contact with you very soon. Feel free to continue to browse the company website.");
    die;
?>
```

Comment: Did you install/configure any mail server ? (Like Postfix Mail Server)

Comment: not not really - i m a newbie on this .. could you guide me on this one thanks :P

Comment: I can try ! What is your environment ? (Linux, Windows, osx ?)

Comment: Maybe you can find how to do this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288007/php-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: my environment is windows

Comment: Save the returned values from the mail function in a variable. Check if it actually sending email or not. Another thing you need to do is turn on all the errors and warning to check what is the issue. error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: email is not being sent - but the form corresponds to the submit id

Comment: now that that i turned display all errors - the page just loads and loads and nothing happens

Comment: ok it did show me the final message only

Comment: but no errors displayed