# Why sending email doesn't work?

Tags: php, email, xampp

I use XAMPP and I've set my configuration based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost#18185233). Also here is my script:

```
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
mail("someone@example.com@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);
```

When I execute it, the result is a blank page without any error. But I don't see any new email in that gmail's inbox. What's wrong and how can I find the problem?

**Notes:**

- I tested that by multiple different gmail accounts.
- I've set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in my script to see any error. *(which there isn't any one)*
- I'm from Iran (I'm not sure it is important)
- I've tested `SMTP port`, and the port numbers are the same

Comment: is this `someone@example.com@gmail.com`valid email address??

Comment: @FrayneKonok Yes .. I write that email address just as an example.

Comment: From my experience mail on localhost doesn't work even with all the smtp config. Try a live server, it'll save you all the hassle. Plus from your code above, the provided email is invalid.

Comment: mail() does not returns error as i know, try sending email on live server not localhost

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi Well that's too bad .. because I don't access a real server right now and I need to check my app.

Comment: I'm sure you can get a hold of a free live test server to test your script. Don't know any off the top of my head but you can google.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi ok thank you.

Comment: Alternatively you can look into phpmailer, I can't say for sure if that would work on you localserver but it's an alternative.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi I see. ok I'll take a look at it.

Comment: This link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288007/php-send-mail-from-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Its quite unlikely that remote mail servers will accept mail from your desktop for various reasons (IP reputation, dns black lists, SPF,etc).

The better approach would be to use phpmailer in your PHP app and then use that to connect and send from a proper SMTP server.

Over and above that, your local PC might not even have any MTA installed so it might just be that it can't send mail.

Answer (score 1):

1. I hope you noticed that you wrote wrong email address
2. Try this:

> ```
> $to      = 'any@example.com';
> $subject = 'subject';
> $message = 'hey';
> $headers = 'From: me@example.com' . "\r\n" .
> 'Reply-To: me@example.com' . "\r\n" .
> 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
> mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
> ```