# Email not receiving in php form although it has been submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

I was making a html form and when ever someone submit after filling info in it , it should go to my email  "nishancofficial@gmail.com". I uploaded my code into website www.nishan.ga/form.html and i fill information for testing it and when I click Submit it say "Submitted" but I waited for long time but it didn't arrived to my gmail address. Can anyone help me!

This is form.html page

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send.php">

<table width="450px">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email">Email Address *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="comments">Comments *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is send.php page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "nishancofficial@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "User Email";





function died($error) {

// your error code can go here

echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

echo $error."<br /><br />";

echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

!isset($_POST['email']) ||



!isset($_POST['comments'])) {

died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); 

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required



$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



THANK you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

What am i missing here.

Comment: Did you check your spam folder? In the past, I've noticed "spoofed" emails land there. Google may see it as an invalid "from" address since it's not coming from their service directly.

Comment: I checked spam but didn't received?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work. However, I did notice a small error in your posted code in the `form.html`. There is an extra `"` at line 13.

There are other questions on StackOverflow regarding PHP Mail [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288007/php-send-mail-from-localhost) you'll need to make sure you have a mail server installed on your server (localhost or other) that allows you to send email with the mail function.