# How to send e-mail in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, email

How do I send mails using PHP? I'm pretty much confused about what I should do.

What does PhpMailer do? If I have a normal HTML file like this how will I code it to mail?

```
<div class="mail-grids">
  <div class="col-md-6 mail-grid-left animated wow slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input name="Name" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" type="text" value="Name">
      <input name="Email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" type="email" value="Email">
      <input name="Subject" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Subject';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" type="text" value="Subject">
      <textarea name="Message" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message...';}" onfocus="this.value = '';" required="" type="text">Message...
      </textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Now" style="margin-left: 378px;">
      </input>
      </input>
      </input>
      </input>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a in built mail function in PHP.

Syntax is

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string
>   $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

For more clarification read this document [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

But if your files are in local computer,(wamp or xamp) using php mail function is quite confusing. Because you have to configure smtp settings. Refer this post for settings : [php send mail from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288007/php-send-mail-from-localhost).

There you can use PHP mailer. For this there are some well developed tutorials. I am providing some.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/

Comment: thank you sridharan